# How do I pass multiple variables to a buttons onClick method in Android?

Tags: android, variables, onclick

I know I can pass a single variable with `android:tag="x"` and retrieve it with `view.getTag()`.

How can I pass and retrieve more than one?

EDIT: What I was trying to do was use the `tag` attribute in a button to pass a value to the method invoked when it is clicked. I was wondering if it is possible to use two or more tags in a `Button` element. I have since discovered that I am going about it the wrong way (I'm an android noob). I was trying to use the `Button` in the xml to store button specific data when I should have given it an id, and then used the id in the code to differentiate the buttons.

Comment: Can you please explain the question properly? And if you have tried some code then share that, too.

Comment: Why do you need this? if the data is static (in your Manifest), you can set the data also in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global variable and set values of that variables and can use in button `onClick(...)` method